# Check value of a recursion function on each call

Tags: python, recursion

I calculate `1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + .....` with a recursion. So it is `1 - x*(1 - x*(1 - x*...` and i have to call `1 - x*F(x)` on eacth reccursion step.
Code in Python is here:

```
def F(x, epsilon, k, y, iteration, value):
    if(iteration == k):
        print('run out of iterations', )
        return 1 - x 
    else:
        return 1 - x * F(x, epsilon, k, y, iteration + 1)
```

**I wonder** if there is a way to know an instant value of `F` on a current call. ATM in my opinion, i cant do it. Critics welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by "know an instant value of `F` on a current call"? Do you mean printing each value as it comes, logging each value into a file, looking at it in a debugger, or other? I usually use the last, unless I run into a real problem.

Comment: Any of it - simply printing it out is OKay

Comment: What are `epsilon`, `y`, and `value` for? BTW, you forgot to pass `value` in your recursive call. When asking questions on SO it's best to reduce your code to a [mcve], don't post code using mysterious variables that aren't relevant to the problem you're asking about. FWIW. I assume you know that the result will converge to `1/(1+x)` if `abs(x)<1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple problems or for understanding, I usually just run my debugger (I now use Spyder) and look at the various values changing at various levels of the recursion. If the return value is the problem, as it often is, I make sure to store that value into a local variable before I return it so I can see it directly in the debugger. In your example code that means changing your `return` lines to

```
result = 1 - x
return result
```

and

```
result = 1 - x * F(x, epsilon, k, y, iteration + 1)
return result
```

Of course, in your case you could just have a single `return` line at the end of the function, after the result has been assigned, which is better style anyway. That usually is enough. In a more serious situation I print the values to the console, adding the line

```
print(iteration, result)
```

between the `result =` and `return` lines, perhaps with a pause `input('Press any key to continue...')`after the print. If the problem is really drastic I save the values to a text file, but that loses the immediacy of the viewing at the benefit of storing it for analysis.

Comment: Can You please explain, why the `result` doesnt print always the sam number? I mean, `x` is constant, so `1-x` is constant too.

Comment: Strange things can happen in code, especially in recursive code. In your case I would expect `x` and thus `1-x` to be constant, but something could possibly interfere with that. In debugging you should make as few assumptions as possible and see what is really happening. Of course, your `if` statement means that `1-x` is not necessarily returned, so we expect that `result` will print `1-x` only once, first, at the innermost layer of recursion, and the other `result`s will differ.

Comment: Why do we expect, that it it will be printed only once? the function is called several times, so it will be printed several times! I just wanted a theoretical explanation of how does your solution work. Beacuse i rally cant understand, why does it print out current value, but not calculation recursion till the end.

Comment: I did my print without pause option on `print(F(0.5, 1e-5, 20, 1, 1, 1))` and I got 20 prints of the return values. The first print is in the innermost recursion layer, showing me `1-x`. Later prints show the function values growing closer to the value `2.0/3.0`. That is exactly what I would want to see: *each* function return value, just before it is returned, which is the "current value" of the function and changes over the course of the program. I don't understand what you mean by "not calculation recursion till the end".

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like :

```
def F(x, epsilon, k, y, iteration, value):
    if(iteration == k):
        print('run out of iterations', )
        return 1 - x 
    else:
        a=1 - x * F(x, epsilon, k, y, iteration + 1)
        print a
        return a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put result into variable before returning it, i.e.:

```
def F(x, epsilon, k, y, iteration, value):
    if(iteration == k):
        print('run out of iterations', )
        res = 1 - x
    else:
        res = 1 - x * F(x, epsilon, k, y, iteration + 1)

    print(res)

    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good use case for a [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) function. This is a function that is automatically applied to the "decorated" function, replacing the function with an enhanced version of itself.

For tracing, you can use something like this. This will print all the invocations of your function with the respective parameters and results, all nicely indented so you see what called what.

```
def trace(f):
    trace.depth = 0
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        print("  " * trace.depth, ">", f.__name__, args, kwargs or "")
        trace.depth += 1
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        trace.depth -= 1
        print("  " * trace.depth, "<", res)
        return res
    return _f
```

This way, you do not have to add any `print` statements to the function itself. Just apply the decorator to your function like this:

```
@trace
def F(x, epsilon, k, y, iteration, value):
    ...
```

This is equivalent to `F = trace(F)`; then just call your function.

Here's an example using a simple Fibonacci function:

```
@trace
def fib(n):
    return 1 if n < 2 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

>>> fib(2)
 > fib (2,) 
   > fib (1,) 
   < 1
   > fib (0,) 
   < 1
 < 2
```