# Tracing a recursive function

Tags: python, function, recursion, trace

i have a homework assignment listed below

> Lee has discovered what he thinks is a clever recursive strategy for
> printing the elements in a sequence (string, tuple, or list). He
> reasons that he can get at the first element in a sequence using the 0
> index, and he can obtain a sequence of the rest of the elements by
> slicing from index 1. This strategy is realized in a function that
> expects just the sequence as an argument. If the sequence is not
> empty, the first element in the sequence is printed and then a
> recursive call is executed. On each recursive call, the sequence
> argument is sliced using the range 1:. Here is Lee’s function
> definition:

and the code I have so far, but it really just makes the function print what I test:

```
def printAll(seq):
    if seq:
        print(seq[0])
        printAll(seq[1:])


test_string = "Run it up plenty"
test_tuple = ("tony", "boney", "phoney")
test_list = ["yuji", "megumi","nobara"]
printAll(test_list)
```

the assignment wants:

> Write a program that tests this function and add code to trace the
> argument on each call. Does this function work as expected? If so, are
> there any hidden costs in running it?

I do not like essentially having to ask the straight question from homework, but I do not understand at all how to get the function to be traced for the assignment. I do not even know where to start here.

Comment: tracing the argument would (could) be just printing `seq`, i.e., `def printAll(seq): \ print(f'argument is: {seq}')`

Comment: [*Opinion*]: I believe ‘tracing’ here is likely a poorly chosen term, likely being confused with actually tracing through a call stack; which appears to be too advanced for this type of assignment.   Perhaps the assignment is simply referring to optimally placed print statements, to *track* the progress through the sequence and determine the current position and efficiency; or lack thereof.

Comment: Is the trace expected to be a literal trace using the trace module or a non-literal trace using print statements?

Comment: As for the 2nd part of the question, you could start by timing the execution of the function on sequences of varying lengths to help make a hypothesis on its time complexity. @KIKOSoftware: I think creating a copy of the sequence counts as a hidden cost too.

Comment: [Opinion:] i think the assingment wants me to print indentations on each line of output.

Comment: im still frozen on how to edit this code to work with that in line with the books example.

Comment: i dont know how to integrate a line indentation with the code as print(seq[0]) printAll(seq[1:]) im trying to insert a blank and a counter

Comment: you could wrap the recursive function in another function and stored the outputs as **attribute** (`list`) of the outer function

Comment: It is possible to use a decorator to trace any recursive function without modifying it. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101837) . You use by simply using `@trace` on the line line above the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track both the value of the sequence (as you already do) *and* the recursion depth, then it is indeed nice to use indentation (as you suggested yourself in comments).

You can pass the current indentation as a second argument, which has a default value for when the top-level call is made:

```
def printAll(seq, indent=""):
    if seq:
        print(f"{indent}{seq[0]}")  # print the value with indentation
        printAll(seq[1:], indent + ". ")  # extend the indentation
```

For your example call, this outputs:

```
yuji
. megumi
. . nobara
```

This illustrates that there is a cost in terms of memory, more specifically, stack space. For a sequence of 3 items this is negligible, but if your sequence has 10,000 elements, your recursion depth would also go to 10,000 and your Python configuration might not allow for using so much stack space.

NB: I used f-string syntax, which is a nicer way to do the following:

```
        print(indent + str(seq[0]))
```

Comment: i was able to integrate the code, but the automated site will not allow me to turn it in. i may not understand enough about testing. I am still pretty lost on what the assignment wants from me. I may have missed the mark here.

Comment: If you are submitting your code to a site that verifies it, then you would have received precise instructions about the expected output or return value. If you want help about that, make sure you include in your question the literal quote of the complete code challenge.

Comment: i though i did. The initial post has the gray bar alongside the block quotes from the question itself asks: Write a program that tests this function and add code to trace the argument on each call.  I have the the question itself posted

Comment: i was able to get it submitted with just this: print(f"seq: {seq}") Above the if seq. This whole chapter I was pretty lost on tracing. Im trying to understand why this works, but its hard for my brain to digest

Comment: The part you quoted seems incomplete (it suddenly stops after ":"), and doesn't ask anything. It just tells a story about Lee and explains a bit the function. There is nothing asked there.

Comment: it should read: Write a program that tests this function and add code to trace the argument on each call. Does this function work as expected? If so, are there any hidden costs in running it?

Comment: But how can a question like "are there any hidden costs in running it" be satisfied by submitting code? That seems to ask for a written answer, with explanations that show a deeper understanding of the function, something that a reviewer would need to score. Also "write a program that tests this function" is very vague, and would not involve touching the given code, but writing code outside of this function, code that *calls* this function.

Comment: if you are finding this confusing, as to am i. I am here often due to the nature of these assignments. The instructions can be vague, and may not line up with the material exacty

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using this print(f"seq: {seq}") , but I got it through outside assistance. I am trying to understand what happened to make this work. My book examples did not lead me here, and I worry I missed something here

```
def printAll(seq):
    print(f"seq: {seq}")
    if seq:
        print(seq[0])
        printAll(seq[1:])

test_string = "Run it up plenty"
test_tuple = ("money", "boney", "phoney")
test_list = ["yuji", "megumi","nobara"]
test_string2 = ""
printAll(test_list)
```

as i understand this tracing works because it posts what happens to the sequence itself as the function runs. The book example used indents to emphasize the change so i was able to kind of recreate that but it was not quite in line. I think i just ended up making a program that adds spaces. Tracing must be seeing what happens to the sequence as the list progresses. Seems as though it clears the list to print it all out

Comment: Try the decorator approach mentioned in my comment above. It just works and for any recursive function without any coding.