# Don't understand how this recursion works

Tags: python, recursion

**Hi! I had this task:**

You are given a positive integer n. Each digit of n has a sign according to the following rules:

The most significant digit is assigned a positive sign.
Each other digit has an opposite sign to its adjacent digits.
Return the sum of all digits with their corresponding sign.

> Example 1:
>
> Input: n = 521
> Output: 4 Explanation: (+5) + (-2) + (+1) = 4.

Honestly, I tried many variants and, surprisingly for me, gave the right answer. I can't understand how this recursion work exactly.

```
class Solution(object):
    def alternateDigitSum(self, n):
        n = str(n)
        if len(n) == 0:
            return 0
        for i in n:
            return int(i) - self.alternateDigitSum(n[1:])
```

In my mind, it should work like:

```
5 - self.alternateDigit(21)
```

which is

```
5 - 2  - self.alternateDigit(1)
```

which is

```
5 - 2 - 1 - self.alternateDigit()
```

So the answer should be 2. But why do I get 4(which is correct answer)?

Comment: `5 - self.alternateDigit(21)` is `5 - (2  - self.alternateDigit(1))` which is `5 - (2  - (1))`.

Comment: NB: using `for` makes little sense here. Just do `return int(n[0]) - self.alternateDigitSum(n[1:])`.

Comment: You could easily debug the code by printing the return values to see what's actually happening.

Comment: As a side comment, you have a `return` statement inside of a `for` loop, which guarantees the loop will only run once.

Comment: Relevant: [Understanding how recursive functions work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25676961)

Comment: See [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101837) which gives the code for a decorator which can be used to follow the recursion and show what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> which is

> `5 - 2 - 1 - self.alternateDigit()`

No it is not.

It is `5 - (2 - 1)`, as @Mike'Pomax'Kamerman pointed out.