# why doesnt a recursion stop at a if statement?

Tags: python

```
def add_one(num):
    if num >= 9:
        return num + 1

    total = num + 1
    print(total)

    add_one(total)

mynewtotal = add_one(0)
print(mynewtotal)
```

Output:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
None

im new to phyton and i was stuck on why the output of this code ends with "none" when i expect it to end with a 10 because when num >= 9 then it should return num + 1 which is 9+1=10. i understand that adding return to add_one(total) would fix it. But why?

Comment: `return` only returns from the current function. The last call will `return` 10 to its caller. Which just drops it on the ground since Python does not have implicit returns (or put an other way, Python only has an implicit `return None`)

Comment: There is the code for a useful decorator in this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101837 ) which shows recursion in action. To use it just copy the code and then use `@trace` on the line above the function definition. You will see the return values appearing from the stack.

Comment: For the same reason `def foo(): bar()` would return `None`, rather than the return value of `bar`. Recursive functions aren't different from non-recursive functions in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the section code:

```
mynewtotal = add_one(0)
print(mynewtotal)
```

The function `add_one` doesn't return anything; that is why `mynewtotal` value is `None` and printing it using `print(mynewtotal)` will print `None`

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer sums up the reason why your code is failing.
To achieve what I think you seek:

```
def add_one(num):
    if num >= 9:
        return num + 1
    else:
        return add_one(num + 1)

mynewtotal = add_one(0)
print(mynewtotal)
```